# On a SP Community want alert for specific Category (not all)

Tags: alert, community-site, community, categories

In SharePoint when I go to set alerts, even if I filter down to a specific Category it gives alerts on ALL Categories or Discussions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have a filtered *view*, but the alert works for new/changed *data*. I'm afraid, the alerts will work for the whole discussion only.

You could split the discussion into several ones and set alert for each one.

Comment: ok, that's good to know but unfortunate - I wish they allowed you to set alerts per Category.  There's no other workaround?